# Ubuntu 13.04, connected to WiFi, but no internet access

Tags: wireless, 13.04

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 13.04 desktop (installed yesterday). WiFi has been working fine for many hours, suddenly I can no longer load any pages. I have another laptop running Windows 8 which I'm now using next to my Ubuntu laptop, and wifi is working fine. I've restarted my wifi modem although it appeared to be running fine anyway. I've disconnected, reconnected to my wifi router from the Ubuntu top menu bar. I've reboot my Ubuntu laptop, still cannot load any page although it looks like I'm connected. I had the same problem about a week ago with a new install of Ubuntu 13.04 (I've since reinstalled), and after about half an hour the problem went away. Seems pretty unreliable though, when my Windows laptop is working fine. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

```
$ ping -c5 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 4031ms

$ sudo lshw -class network
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
       vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: e0:b9:a5:2d:1f:bf
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.8.0-26-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:17 memory:de700000-de70ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 06
       serial: bc:ae:c5:64:26:94
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8168e-2.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:41 ioport:9000(size=256) memory:d2104000-d2104fff memory:d2100000-d2103fff

$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev b5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b5)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM65 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 540M] (rev a1)
02:00.0 Multimedia controller: Philips Semiconductors SAA7231 (rev ca)
03:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
04:00.0 USB controller: Fresco Logic FL1000G USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 04)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 06)
```

EDIT2:

```
$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr bc:ae:c5:64:26:94  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:743 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:743 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:50506 (50.5 KB)  TX bytes:50506 (50.5 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e0:b9:a5:2d:1f:bf  
          inet6 addr: fe80::e2b9:a5ff:fe2d:1fbf/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1900 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:982 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:457035 (457.0 KB)  TX bytes:107425 (107.4 KB)

$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 wlan0
```

EDIT3:

```
$ sudo dhclient wlan0
$ ifconfig wlan0
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e0:b9:a5:2d:1f:bf  
          inet addr:192.168.1.5  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::e2b9:a5ff:fe2d:1fbf/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2124 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1170 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:512506 (512.5 KB)  TX bytes:136944 (136.9 KB)
```

Comment: post the output of ifconfig and route -n

Comment: I added the information. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Wlan0 is not getting any IP address. Try sudo dhclient wlan0 .After that provide output of ifconfig wlan0 .

Comment: Now wlan0 got an IP. Can you try pinging google by ping -c 5 google.com and post output.

Comment: Thanks very much. I initially checked "Connection Information" and the IP address was still 0.0.0.0 so I thought it hadn't worked. But then I noticed the IP address in the iwconfig output. I have internet connection again. Do you know why this doesn't happen automatically? I'm very new to Ubuntu (days), so I'm wondering if there are known bugs in this area? I can now run the dhclient command if it happens again thanks to your kind help, but I'm wondering why that's necessary.

Comment: COOL! Glad that it works! Speaking about the connection problem, Ubuntu "shoud" do it automatically without having any hustle.  I can't say if it's a bug or not. But now you know how to fix it. Good to go I guess. Have fun using Ubuntu!

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I don't know how this stackexchange works. If you want to add the command that fixed this in an answer, I can mark it as the correct answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fire up terminal by `Shift + ALT + T`

type

```
 sudo dhclient wlan0
```

Done.