# Fresh Ubuntu Install (12.04), No Internet

Tags: 12.04, installation, wireless, networking, internet

I just performed a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04.3 64-bit, and I cannot connect to the internet.

Ubuntu is installed on its own partition, with Windows 7 on the other. Yet while I'm able to connect to the internet using Windows 7, I am unable to do so using Ubuntu.

I use a Linksys Wireless-G USB network adapter dongle (WUSB54GC). It shows that I am successfully connecting to my router over wi-fi.

I had successful internet connection when I was using the 32-bit version of Ubuntu 12.04.3.

Can you help?

Thank you.

EDIT 1:

```
nicholas@Nicholas:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 20:cf:30:3f:fd:93  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:60 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:60 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:3808 (3.8 KB)  TX bytes:3808 (3.8 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:22:6b:9e:38:92  
          inet addr:192.168.1.119  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::222:6bff:fe9e:3892/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:145 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:127 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:23530 (23.5 KB)  TX bytes:17789 (17.7 KB)
```

Comment: are you able to connect but cant use internet??

Comment: Correct. Connecting to my router, but no internet.

Comment: check it .. and try http://askubuntu.com/questions/321836/ubuntu-13-04-connected-to-wifi-but-no-internet-access

Comment: Please see my `ifconfig` output under 'EDIT 1'. I will try some of the commands given in the link you provided.

Comment: try "sudo dhclient wlan0"...

Comment: Wait -- it's working now! I didn't even have to try `sudo dhclient wlan0`! My internet just started working after logging into Ubuntu this time! Strange, because I _did_ reboot after your first suggestion, and it didn't work then. Now, I'm able to visit webpages (typing this from Ubuntu now), and I've tested by rebooting three times. Whatever you did, thank you Sushantp606! I hope it will hold out...

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know where to check your comment as an Answer. Can you respond in the form of an Answer, or should I enter your solution as one myself?

Comment: which comment .. i will update my  answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try these lines once -

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe -rv wl
sudo modprobe -v brcmsmac
```

answer taken from [here.](https://askubuntu.com/a/384281/192102)

If error comes ignore them and reboot your PC then see if its working.

hope it will work now.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. However, I tried the commands and have not had successful internet connection. 1st: `Reading package lists... Done`, `Building dependency tree`, `Reading state information... Done`, `E: Unable to locate package bcmwl-kernel-source`, 2nd: `FATAL: Module wl not found.`, 3rd: <none>

Comment: paste the output of ifconfig. i am close to the problem.

Comment: Thank you!!! Note: Did not work after first reboot, but after rebooting a second time my internet started working.