# Connected to WiFi but unable to access the Internet

Tags: wireless, networking, internet

As the title says, I can connect to WiFi network, but however, I cannot access any of the website over internet. I have just installed a fresh Ubuntu distribution on to my MacBook Pro so I am new to Linux.

I am also not sure what other info to provide. So please advise me in this regard & what type of information needed to help me solve this issue.

I am currently on Ubuntu 13.10.

Output of ifconfig:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 10:9a:dd:4d:4d:f0  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:16 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1296 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1296 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:98244 (98.2 KB)  TX bytes:98244 (98.2 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c8:bc:c8:ef:e4:0d  
          inet addr:192.168.0.192  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::cabc:c8ff:feef:e40d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2895 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2513 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:820807 (820.8 KB)  TX bytes:321270 (321.2 KB)
```

Output of iwconfig:

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"kpke4 Home Network"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 00:22:B0:B0:98:3B   
          Bit Rate=130 Mb/s   Tx-Power=19 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=55/70  Signal level=-55 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:11   Missed beacon:0
```

Output for **ping -c5 8.8.8.8**

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data. 
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=47 time=35.2 ms 
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=47 time=36.8 ms 
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=47 time=50.3 ms 
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=47 time=35.9 ms 
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=5 ttl=47 time=35.4 ms 
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics --- 
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 35.257/38.778/50.372/5.827 ms
```

Output of **route -n**

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
```

Comment: Yes, the router shows the connections from my laptop.

Comment: what was the output of `ping -c5 8.8.8.8`?

Comment: Output of ping -c5 8.8.8.8
`kenny@kenny-MacBookPro:~$ ping -c5 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=47 time=35.2 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=47 time=36.8 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=47 time=50.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=47 time=35.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=5 ttl=47 time=35.4 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 35.257/38.778/50.372/5.827 ms`

Comment: Hi **exload**, I would suggest you to [**edit**](http://askubuntu.com/posts/417088/edit) question and add the output within the question itself. This way it is easy for us to assist you better. Further by looking at your **ping** results, you've got not loss, which means internet connectivity is there

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/321836/ubuntu-13-04-connected-to-wifi-but-no-internet-access

Comment: Once again may I please request you to [**edit**](http://askubuntu.com/posts/417088/edit) your question and post the output for `route -n`. (:

Comment: When I attempt do `sudo dhclient wlan0` all that gets returned is `RTNETLINK answers: File exists` and I am still unable to connect to any webpages.

Comment: try http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2192496

Comment: Disconnect from wireless & do `cd /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`, then type `ls` to see access points. After use `sudo rm your_access_point_name` to remove your access point. Then do `sudo service network-manager restart`. Finally try connecting to WiFi & check whether you're able to.

Comment: I ran `sudo modprobe brcmsmac` and it is working now! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Great! You may add it to the answer by linking the source & accept it as answer.

Comment: Kindly provide the output of the following 3 commands; `ping www.google.com` `tracepath www.google.com` `dig www.google.com`

Answer (score 0):

Check your DNS settings. Who is the DHCP server? And what DNS server does the DHCP distribute?